# Is there a function to compact a JSON?

Tags: terraform

I have a JSON file. I need to pass contents of this file to a terraform resource.

If I just pass it as it is, then the file has newlines and whitespace. I want to remove that and send compact JSON.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5526#issuecomment-552028124), you can do it via a round-trip:

> As of Terraform 0.12, you can produce minified JSON using a round-trip through `jsondecode` and `jsonencode`, because `jsonencode` always produces minimal JSON:
>
> ```
> policy = jsonencode(jsondecode(templatefile("filename.tpl", {})))
> ```